# I built a Social Network, how can i be seen as Social Network in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, social-networking

I built a **Social Network**, and i would like to know how can i be seen as Social Network in **Google Analytics** for the traffic i send?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be once your network grows significant enough for Google add it to their default grouping.

The other option is for you to add a “linker” something to be between your site and the sites you’re sending traffic to.

Example:

1. Someone posts a link to www.mysite.com on your site.
2. Your site modified that site to www.mysocialnetwork.com/links?redirect=www.mysite.com?utm_source=mysocialnetwork&utm_medium=social

But the above would only work if the sites you’re redirecting to also uses GA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) I'm gonna use your second option for now until the site grows enough